In Pandas, how do you groupby and call an agg function on only one column while keeping the corresponding values in the other columns in the same rows
I need to do this while keeping the group by index of the grouped by Column as the index. I can’t use reset_index etc. there are multiple columns I need to keep. I only want to call an agh function on one column, grouped by another, while keeping all the other columns with their values unaffected by agg and attached to their original row in the aggregated column. The agg function I’m using is max so it is a specific row.
When I try to achieve this I can’t do it without having the max function called on other columns and then the values are no longer matched properly. I have looked at solutions online but none of them apply here as they all involve changing the index from the group by index.

Replace agg by transform, which will broadcast the output of the aggregation to all original rows

That just returns a series and the series isn’t even correct.

Then please provide a [mre] and clearly demonstrate what you want and how transform would fail. "I have looked at solutions online but none of them apply" is not a good explanation. [ask].
